# TTreeView drawing error when deactivating a form

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have found what appears to be a bug related to `TTreeView`.

- Take a form containing a `TTreeView` with `HideSelection` set to `True`.
- Make the tree view multi-select and select multiple items in the tree view.
- Show another form so that your app has two forms.
- Give the tree view the focus and then click in the other form.

The result looks like this:

[image]

But in fact there should be no items highlighted. Interestingly, the last item is selected and it is no longer highlighted, as indeed should all the other items. It appears that the most recently clicked item is the one that gets the special treatment.

If instead you click in the edit box (or indeed any other control that takes focus) then all items are correctly hidden. So it's fine for the focus to transfer to another control on the form—the problem seems to be limited to deactivating the form.

I have discovered by trial and error that I can fix this by calling `Invalidate` on the tree view whenever the form is deactivated and activated (need to prevent mirror image of the bug). However, I'm looking for a better understanding of what the bug is and how to fix it in a less invasive manner, i.e. at the tree view level rather than the containing form level.

So, to summarise, my questions are:

1. What exactly is causing the problem?
2. How can I fix it without writing code that hooks `TForm` events?

---

Submitted the issue as [QC#94908](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=94908).

Comment: I've tried this and the same is also in D2009. Exactly as you said the item which has focus hides it; the rest remains higlighted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution seems to be to respond to [`NM_SETFOCUS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773497%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [`NM_KILLFOCUS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773479%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) notifications by invalidating selected nodes. You can modify `TCustomTreeView.CNNotify` directly or you can write a new `TCustomTreeView` descendant. Here is a quick hack only to show the missing code:

```
type
  TTreeView = class(ComCtrls.TTreeView)
  private
    procedure CNNotify(var Message: TWMNotifyTV); message CN_NOTIFY;
  end;

procedure TTreeView.CNNotify(var Message: TWMNotifyTV);
begin
  case Message.NMHdr^.code of
    NM_KILLFOCUS, NM_SETFOCUS:
      InvalidateSelectionsRects;
  end;
  inherited;
end;
```

**Edit**: David's [QC report](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=94908).

Comment: No need for a descendant. Your interceptor approach is exactly what we often use in these situations. We usually code a fix like this in a separate unit that we just include after all the standard stuff in the uses. And to recognize these units, they are all called <name of control>Fix.pas...

Comment: This solves my problem and is exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks for bringing your superior knowledge to bear to my little problem!  Now I'll submit a QC report.

Comment: @Marjan As it happens I am already using the descendant approach. In fact I happen also to be compiling my own version of ComCtrls.pas to fix other bugs that can't be reached from outside that unit.

Comment: @David Thanks! I'm glad I could help. BTW, I've found that the same problem was also happening when switching to another application (not just to another form within the same application). The code above seems to solve that case, too.